# How to return multi-line results, on same line? - ('Drawing' integers)

Tags: python

The PrintInteger function below takes a list of non-negative numbers (ex: 345) and then prints each corresponding 'picture', ex:

```
###
  #
###
  #
###

# #
# #
###
  #
  #

###
#
###
  #
###
```

I would like the output to appear like this, but can't figure it out.  Thanks in advance!

```
### # # ###
  # # # #
### ### ###
  #   #   #
###   # ###
```

```
    def PrintInteger(i):
        y=''
        for x in i:
            x=int(x)
            print(lst[x-1])

    lst=['#\n#\n#\n#\n#',
             '###\n  #\n###\n#\n###',
             '###\n  #\n###\n  #\n###',
             '# #\n# #\n###\n  #\n  #',
             '###\n#\n###\n  #\n###',
             '###\n#\n###\n# #\n###',
             '###\n  #\n  #\n  #\n  #',
             '###\n# #\n###\n# #\n###',
             '###\n# #\n###\n  #\n###',
             '###\n# #\n# #\n# #\n###']
    i=input("Please enter a list of non-negative integer numbers: ")
    PrintInteger(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each letter representation has newlines in between, each one is printed one at a time. Instead, you can split them into components based on the newline character and print out each character's component before moving on the next line for all characters:

```
def PrintInteger(i):
    y=''
    for idx in range(5): # each string has 4 newline characters, so 5 components
        for x in i:
            x=int(x)
            print(lst[x - 1].split('\n')[idx], end='\t') # print each characters component for this line
        print('') # create newline
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for something like this

your question is not clear !

```
y=''
for x in i:
    y += str(x) + ' '
print(y)
```

Simple way

```
y = ' '.join(str(x) for x in i)
print(y)
```

Comment: This just joins the numbers entered.  awarrier99's answer joins the lines.